# Is there a good way to intercept and log MIDI over BLE traffic?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, reverse-engineering, midi

Is there a good way to "man in the middle" MIDI BLE traffic (not for anything nefarious - I'm trying to find the interface the Teenage Engineering OP-Z uses to talk to its iOS app) I have both MacOS and Windows environments available. I'm aware of *midipipe* on the Mac, but it only seems to be able to join one MIDI BLE source at a time, and thus cannot forward the traffic to the destination.

Comment: It's probably going to be a lot easier to proxy the data through your application/device to capture it.

Comment: That would be fine, it's what *midipipe* can do for physical connections, but not BLE.

Answer (score 0):

**Bome MIDI Translator Pro** turns out to be able to do this using its Log window, which is fully available in the free version.